# Using collections.Counter to count elements in sublists

Tags: python, python-2.7, counter, tokenize

I have a list of tokenized text sentences (youtube comments):

```
sample_tok = [['How', 'does', 'it', 'call', 'them', '?', '\xef\xbb\xbf'], 
              ['Thats', 'smart\xef\xbb\xbf'], 
              ... # and sooo on.....
              ['1:45', ':', 'O', '\xef\xbb\xbf']]
```

Now I want to make a dictionary with the words and the amount of times they are mentioned.

```
from collections import Counter

d = Counter()
for sent in [sample_tok]:
    for words in sent:
        d = Counter(words)
```

Unfortunately, this just counts the last sublist...

```
[(':', 1), ('1:45', 1), ('\xef\xbb\xbf', 1), ('O', 1)]
```

Is there a way to make it count all the tokenized sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **replacing** your counter, not updating it. Each time in the loop you produce a new `Counter()` instance, discarding the previous copy.

Pass each word in a nested generator expression to your `Counter()`:

```
d = Counter(word for sublist in sample_tok for word in sublist)
```

or, if you need to somehow process each sublist first, use [`Counter.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update):

```
d = Counter()
for sent in [sample_tok]:
    for words in sent:
        d.update(words)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `update` method of Counter instances. This counts the passed values and adds them to the counter.

```
d = Counter()
for sent in [sample_tok]:
    for words in sent:
        d.update(words)
```

Or you can add the new counter to the old one:

```
d = Counter()
for sent in [sample_tok]:
    for words in sent:
        d += Counter(words)
```